# pytest and Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, django-testing, pytest-django

During invoking **pytest** from the shell I get the following output, because my test is stored in **apps.business.metrics.tools.tests.py**, and during import of the module

`apps/business/metrics/widgets/employees/utilization.py`

makes a live call to SQL during module invocation. This is done by

`get_metric_columns('EmployeeUtilization', shapers=SHAPERS)`

and pytest complaints:

```
➜ pytest
=========================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================
platform linux -- Python 3.6.8, pytest-4.0.0, py-1.7.0, pluggy-0.8.0
Django settings: config.settings.local (from ini file)
rootdir: /home/dmitry/Projects/analytics/backend, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-3.4.7, pylama-7.6.6, django-test-plus-1.1.1, celery-4.2.1
collected 60 items / 1 errors                                                                                                                                             

================================================================================= ERRORS ==================================================================================
__________________________________________________________ ERROR collecting apps/business/metrics/tools.tests.py __________________________________________________________
../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/envs/cam/lib/python3.6/site-packages/py/_path/local.py:668: in pyimport
    __import__(modname)
apps/business/metrics/__init__.py:3: in <module>
    from .widgets import *  # noqa
apps/business/metrics/widgets/__init__.py:1: in <module>
    from . import help  # noqa
apps/business/metrics/widgets/help.py:1: in <module>
    from .employees.utilization import EmployeeSwarmUtilization
apps/business/metrics/widgets/employees/utilization.py:19: in <module>
    get_metric_columns('EmployeeUtilization', shapers=SHAPERS)
apps/business/metrics/tools.py:132: in get_metric_columns
    m = get_metric(metric, period=p, shapers=shapers)
apps/business/metrics/data/__init__.py:23: in get_metric
    return metrics[name](*args, **kwargs)
apps/business/metrics/data/abstract.py:441: in __init__
    self._to_dataframe(self.sql or self._ingest())
apps/business/metrics/data/abstract.py:472: in _to_dataframe
    source, connection, params=query_params, index_col=self.index
../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/envs/cam/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:381: in read_sql
    chunksize=chunksize)
../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/envs/cam/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:1413: in read_query
    cursor = self.execute(*args)
../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/envs/cam/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py:1373: in execute
    cur = self.con.cursor()
../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/envs/cam/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:255: in cursor
    return self._cursor()
../../../.pyenv/versions/3.6.8/envs/cam/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py:232: in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
E   Failed: Database access not allowed, use the "django_db" mark, or the "db" or "transactional_db" fixtures to enable it.
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
========================================================================= 1 error in 2.43 seconds =========================================================================
```

#### Is there a way to handle such situation with pytest?

I understand I can convert the **get_metric_columns('EmployeeUtilization', shapers=SHAPERS)** into a partial func and change the implementation, but is there any other way around?

Comment: https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/database.html#database-access

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Solution:

```
import pytest


@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestExample:
    def test_one():
        ...
```

Assume that you've created a `TestExample` class inside your test file and it should be decorated with `@pytest.mark.django_db`. It should solve your problem.

Comment: In my case, get the same error even after adding `@pytest.mark.django_db`. Any suggestion to fix it? @Ahsan

Comment: My code has never needed this and then it suddenly did today. So confused...

Answer (score 10):

Another way to solve this is to inherit from the Django `TestCase` in your test class:

```
from django.test import TestCase


class TestExampleTestCase(TestCase):
    def test_one():
        ...
```

**Make sure you import `django.test.TestCase` and not `unittest.TestCase`.**

The accepted answer should also work, but this will give you additional tooling provided by the Django test framework and is the standard way of writing tests according to the [official Django docs on testing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/testing/overview/).

Comment: This is probably the common case for Django-based applications.

Comment: This was the issue for me. Inheriting from unittest worked in my local environment but not in the CI environment (github actions).

Answer (score 5):

As the error suggests, you should use [@pytest.mark.django_db](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#pytest-mark-django-db-request-database-access), [db](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#std-fixture-db) or [transactional_db](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/helpers.html#transactional-db).

`@pytest.mark.django_db`:

```py
import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.mark.django_db # Here
def test_1():
    count = User.objects.all().count()    
    assert count == 0
```

`db`:

```py
import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
         # ↓↓ Here
def test_1(db):
    count = User.objects.all().count()    
    assert count == 0
```

`transactional_db`:

```py
import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import User
         # ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓
def test_1(transactional_db):
    count = User.objects.all().count()    
    assert count == 0
```

`@pytest.mark.django_db` with [@pytest.fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#pytest-fixture):

```py
import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_1():
    count = User.objects.all().count() 
    return count

@pytest.mark.django_db # Here
def test_1(fixture_1):
    count = fixture_1
    assert count == 0
```

`test_1(db, fixture_1)` with `@pytest.fixture`:

```py
import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_1():
    count = User.objects.all().count() 
    return count
         # ↓↓ Here
def test_1(db, fixture_1):
    count = fixture_1
    assert count == 0
```

`fixture_1(db)` with `@pytest.fixture`:

```py
import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_1(db): # <- db
    count = User.objects.all().count() 
    return count

def test_1(fixture_1):
    count = fixture_1
    assert count == 0
```

`test_1(transactional_db, fixture_1)` with `@pytest.fixture`:

```py
import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_1():
    count = User.objects.all().count() 
    return count
         # ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓
def test_1(transactional_db, fixture_1):
    count = fixture_1
    assert count == 0
```

`fixture_1(transactional_db)` with `@pytest.fixture`:

```py
import pytest

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

@pytest.fixture
def fixture_1(transactional_db): # <- transactional_db
    count = User.objects.all().count() 
    return count

def test_1(fixture_1):
    count = fixture_1
    assert count == 0
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have the mark and you're still getting the error, ensure you're **not** accessing the database from outside a test function.

For example:

```py
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestEndpoint:
    user = User.objects.create()    # Accessing the database outside a test function will raise the error

    def test_endpoint(self):
        pass
```

Rather, move any code that accesses the database into the test function. If it's an object you wanna re-use, I suggest making it a fixture.